# Open UI datepicker calendar upside/downside

Tags: jquery, angularjs, uidatepicker

I am using Boot strap calendar ui-datepicker and using below code to popup calendar.

```
<input type="text" name="expectedClosedDate" class="form-control width-160 float-left" uib-datepicker-popup="{{expectedClosedDate.format}}" min-date="minDate" ng-model="ideaDetail.Idea.ExpectedCloseDate" datepicker-options="expectedClosedDate.dateOptions" close-text="Close" is-open="expectedClosedDate.isOpened" disabled date-disabled="expectedClosedDate.disabled(date, mode)" />
            <span class="addon-brit input-group-addon mouse-hand float-left" ng-click="expectedClosedDate.open()" style="width:50px;line-height: 1.68">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
```

Problem is, it opens calendar downside, and as per my UI I would like to open it upside. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datepicker element is created below the input by default. There is a style on that pate picker element:

```
    display: block;
    top: 34px;
    left: 0px;
```

The picker height is about 288px, so if you set the `top` as `-290px`, then it will be above the input.

So you can use css to do that. The idea is: give an id to the input, set the style of the next `ul` element of that input as mentioned above.